# Renaming feature classes in model builder gives error 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, error-999999, feature-dataset

I've a simple model to iterate through a feature dataset and rename all the feature classes, adding "geo." before the original filenames. The output of Rename tool looks like "geo.%Name%", but running the model i get Error 999999 message, i think it's because of the point after "geo", so i'd like to ask if there is a way to keep the point in the filename, but for the tool to ignore it and run the command?

Comment: You think that it is because of the point after "geo" but have you tested with and without to be certain?  If so, then I suspect that you are violating a geodatabase naming convention and may need to stop doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the point, that is an invalid character to use in a feature class name. More information about *Defining feature class properties* including naming conventions is discussed on this [page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/feature-classes/defining-feature-class-properties.htm).

If you want to separate geo from name then use an underscore.

Comment: You're right, looks like there's no way to put a point in the name of feature class, so i'll just use underscore instead of point, as you suggested. Thank you!